# Unable to change a state variable in a contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am developing an Ethereum contract using Truffle and TestRPC. But I am unable to get a state variable to update. I think it might just be that I'm accessing it too early, but other example tests seem to work just fine and are very similar.

I have reduced my contract down to the simplest possible thing that breaks:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Adder {

    uint public total;

    function add(uint amount) {
        total += amount;
    }

    function getTotal() returns(uint){
        return total;
    }
}
```

And this is my test:

```
var Adder = artifacts.require("./Adder.sol");

contract('Adder', accounts => {
  it("should start with 0", () =>
    Adder.deployed()
      .then(instance => instance.getTotal.call())
      .then(total => assert.equal(total.toNumber(), 0))
  );

  it("should increase the total as amounts are added", () =>
    Adder.deployed()
      .then(instance => instance.add.call(10)
        .then(() => instance.getTotal.call())
        .then(total => assert.equal(total.toNumber(), 10))
      )
  );

});
```

The first test passes ok. But the second test fails because `getTotal` is still returning 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the issue is that you are always using the `.call()` method.

This method will, in fact, execute the code but will not save to the blockchain.

You should use the `.call()` method, only when reading from the blockchain or testing for `throws`.

Just remove the `.call()` in the adding function and it should work.

```
var Adder = artifacts.require("./Adder.sol");

contract('Adder', accounts => {
  it("should start with 0", () =>
    Adder.deployed()
      .then(instance => instance.getTotal.call())
      .then(total => assert.equal(total.toNumber(), 0))
  );

  it("should increase the total as amounts are added", () =>
    Adder.deployed()
      .then(instance => instance.add(10)
        .then(() => instance.getTotal.call())
        .then(total => assert.equal(total.toNumber(), 10))
      )
  );
});
```

Also, consider declaring the `instance` variable outside the chain of functions of the promise since the context is not shared. Consider using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for tests instead of promises.

```
var Adder = artifacts.require("./Adder.sol");

contract('Adder', accounts => {
  it("should start with 0", async () => {
    let instance = await Adder.deployed();
    assert.equal((await instance.getTotal.call()).toNumber(), 0);
  });

  it("should increase the total as amounts are added", async () => {
    let instance = await Adder.deployed();
    await instance.add(10);
    assert.equal((await instance.getTotal.call()).toNumber(), 10);
  });
});
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple!

Comment: This needs more upvotes. I was stuck on this for 2 hours before i came upon this answer